# Error with tag assert in schema ORA-06512: en "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA"

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following error when run this code:

```
ERROR en lÝnea 1: ORA-30937: No hay ninguna definici¾n de esquema para
'assert' (espacio de nombres 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema') en el
principal
 '/schema/element[1]/complexType/sequence/element[1]/complexType/sequence/element[3]/complexType' 
ORA-06512: en "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA_INT", lÝnea 3
ORA-06512: en "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA", lÝnea 14 
ORA-06512: en lÝnea 31
```

The code is pl/sql version oracle BD 11g

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0

### Code:

```
declare
  doc varchar2(30000) := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
  <xs:element name="root" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="node">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="info" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="detail">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:assert test="((type = ''B'') and detail) or (type=''A'')" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';

begin
        dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema('procesos/gsioper/solicitudes/solicitud5.xsd', doc);
end;
```

I want to implement a XSD Schema when the tag type = 'B', it is mandatory to register the tag detail
like this:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <info>info</info>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <info>info</info>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>B</type>
        <info>info</info>
        <detail>
            <name>john</name>
            <address>downtown</address>
        </detail>
    </node>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support XSD 1.1, which is required for `xs:assert`.

You'll have to remove `xs:assert` and forgo (or find a non-XSD-based alternative for) enforcing its constraint.